# Is there any other solution to solve this problem?

Tags: java

My code should call the method 1 if input equals to cat and method 2 if the input equals to dog. For acheiving this I have used a if else condition but Iam curious to know if it is possible to implement in another way without the use of if or switch or hashmap function in java. Can someone suggest a solution for this?

```
if(input.equals("cat")) 
   method1()
else if(input.equals("dog")) 
   method2()
```

Comment: you can indeed use a switch of a map of functions

Comment: Did you mean `else if`?

Comment: What is wrong with `if` or `switch`?

Comment: "is it possible" sure it's possible to get creative and come up with more complicated ways to do it but *why would you*

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're looking for some polymorphic implementation.

It is feasible via enums and functional interfaces:

```
class MyClass {
    static void method1() {
        System.out.println("meow");
    }

    static void method2() {
        System.out.println("woof");
    }

    enum MyEnum {
        CAT(MyClass::method1),
        DOG(MyClass::method2);


        private MyEnum(Runnable method) {
            this.runnable = method;
        }

        private final Runnable runnable;

        public void act() {
            System.out.print(name() + ": ");
            this.runnable.run();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] inputs = {"cat", "dog" };
        for (String input : inputs) {
            MyEnum animal = MyEnum.valueOf(input.toUpperCase());
            animal.act();
        }
    }
}
```

It will output:

```
CAT: meow
DOG: woof
```

But anyway under the hood the `Enum`'s method `valueOf` [is using a package-private map `enumConstantDirectory`](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/Enum.java) to get the enum value by the name.

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType,
                                                String name) {
        T result = enumType.enumConstantDirectory().get(name);
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use reflection?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void cat(){
        System.out.println("meow");
    }
    
    public static void dog(){
        System.out.println("bark");
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Method m = Ideone.class.getDeclaredMethod("cat");
        m.invoke(Ideone.class);
        m = Ideone.class.getDeclaredMethod("dog");
        m.invoke(Ideone.class);
    }
}
```

For starters fragile, and if you're using user input you've just exposed every public method.